# My Subsurface Scattering Material doesn't look as expected

Tags: materials, shaders, subsurface-scattering

I wanted to make a certain soap with this kind of look
So here's my reference:

[image]

After seeing that, I immediately thought of bumping subsurface scattering,
so I made this simple material with a pretty high SSS:

[image]

I tweaked a lot with the SSS and the color but couldn't achieve what I wanted. Maybe the problem is because of the lighting too? I don't really know, I'm really new with SSS.

Here's what I have achieved so far:

[image]

Comment: SSS lighting is heavily light-dependent (like how you can see the "red" through your hand only if you hold a flashlight up to it). For something like soap, I still think 0.4 is a high enough value - anything over that and you start getting banded "internal shadows" that look unrealistic from any angle.

Comment: If you use a mix shader and a Layer Weight as the factor, you can probably get that look.

Comment: i tried layer weight with fresnel before, but its still pretty hard to get it, 
i also didn't change the subsurface radius, do i need to tweak it or anything ?

Comment: How big is your soap block? The smaller it is the more light can enter and scatter around. If you have used the default cube ...you know it's 2m large. Try *"Random Walk" (2nd drop-down list of the P. BSDF. This uses the mesh's volume.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask - are you planning on using Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: im planning on using cycles because the other shots im using cycles. just to make it look similar. but if its achieveable in eevee and doesnt look to different, no problem.

Comment: @Blunder it's pretty thick like a normal soap bar. then i also thought like u did, so i make the saop block super thin, since it will be previewed super frontal, like in how i showed on the screen shots. okay I'll try random walk

Answer (score 0):

See my setup below.

It's a common misconception of how you use SSS. SSS color should determine the base color, while subsurface radius actually determines the color.
[image]